# How to proxy over ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, telegram, vps

I have vps server where I have access to api.telegram.org, but on my local machine I could not get it.

I'm developing long poll bot for telegram, and now I need my bot to work locally - I think I can obtain it using ssh port forwarding but I dont know how to do it - I need to be able to use api.telegram.org throw my local machine over ssh to my vps

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 100"  -L  vps_server_ip:5000:api.telegram.org:80  some_vps_server_user@vps_server
```

This will redirect the request coming on port 5000 of `vps_server` to `api.telegram.org` at Port 80 .

Your bot has to connect to `vps_server:5000` to access `api.telegram.org`